# Renaming hstore key in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I've been evaluating PostgreSQL's hstore functionality (9.2) and the only thing the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) isn't explicit about is how to rename keys. For instance, how could I rename the  key `c` to `ai_count`?

`"c"=>"3", "ai_voltage"=>"3", "ai_temperature"=>"28"`

I'm thinking there is no direct way to do this and that it involves duplicating the `c` key to a `ai_count` key, then dropping the `c` key. How can I do this, ideally as a one-liner which can be applied to multiple records?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're right that you have to pull the old pair out and put the new pair (with the renamed key) back in.

You could do it with a one-liner:

```
(h - from_key) || hstore(to_key, h -> from_key)
```

where `h` is the hstore, `from_key` is the key you want to change and `to_key` is what you want to change it to. That will return a new hstore with the desired change but it assumes that `from_key` is in `h`; if `from_key` isn't in `h` then you'll end up with a `to_key -> NULL` in your hstore. If you, like all sane people, don't want the stray NULL then I'd wrap the logic in a simple function to make it easier to add an existence check; something like this:

```
create or replace function
change_hstore_key(h hstore, from_key text, to_key text) returns hstore as $$
begin
    if h ? from_key then
        return (h - from_key) || hstore(to_key, h -> from_key);
    end if;
    return h;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then you can say both of these and get the expected results:

```
=> select change_hstore_key('a=>1,b=>2,c=>3'::hstore, 'b', 'pancakes');
      change_hstore_key       
------------------------------
 "pancakes"=>"2", "a"=>"1", "c"=>"3"

=> select change_hstore_key('a=>1,b=>2,c=>3'::hstore, 'pancakes', 'X');
      change_hstore_key       
------------------------------
 "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3"
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it fast for ~1 million records with hstore column when renaming multiple keys at once? I'm on 9.3.

Comment: @szimek: AFAIK you'd have to open each hstore, fix it up, and put it back (i.e. the hard way as above). You could try asking another question so that some of real PostgreSQL experts could help.

Comment: to avoid adding NULL values you might want to filter the records you update with `WHERE h ? from_key`