# How to rename hstore key in Rails + Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hstore

How to rename hstore key in Rails 4 with Postgres?

```
User.update_all('hstorename -> oldcolumname: newcolumnname') ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276545/305019

```
  def change_hstore_key(klass, h, from_key, to_key)
    klass.where("#{h} ? '#{from_key}'")
         .update_all("#{h} = (#{h} - '#{from_key}'::text) || " \
                     "hstore('#{to_key}'::text, #{h} -> '#{from_key}')")
  end

  # usage
  change_hstore_key(User, hstorename, oldcolumnname, newcolumnname)
```

**IMPORTANT**: Do not use this with any user-supplied params to avoid SQL injection. For migrations etc where you provide all data, this should do the trick.